# Как передать id в ajax по клику

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Делаю корзину, много товаров, хотел прикрутить ajax на тык по кнопке, не могу понять как передать значение $cartItem->rowId для удаления выбранного товара из корзины.. Можно ли получать это значение не из скрытых инпутов? Ну, или как будет сделать это правильнее. Пока работает по тыку на ссылку

Вьюшка:

```
<div id="cart">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Моя корзина ({{Cart::count()}})</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($cartItems as $cartItem)
            <tr>
                <td><img src="{{url('img',$cartItem->options->image)}}"></td>
                <td><p>{{$cartItem->name}}</p></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="number" size="2" value="{{$cartItem->qty}}" min="1"></td>
                <td><p>{{$cartItem->subtotal(0,'',',')}} ₽</p></td>
                <td><button class="btn" id="removeItem"><a href="{{url('/cart/removeItem')}}/{{$cartItem->rowId}}"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></button></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><button>Оформить заказ</button></td>
            <td colspan="2">{{Cart::total()}} ₽</td>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

Собственно сам запрос который я накидал

```
$(".removeItem").click(getRemoveItem);

function getRemoveItem(e) {

    var rowId =  ????

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '{{url('/cart/removeItem')}}/'+rowId,
        data: {
                    ??
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#cart').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Где кнопка "Удалить" пишешь так:

```
<button class="btn removeItem" data-id="{{$cartItem->rowId}}"><a href="{{url('/cart/removeItem')}}/{{$cartItem->rowId}}"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a></button>
```

В js обращаешься к полю data-id вот так:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.removeItem').on('click', function (event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var rowId = this.dataset.id;

        // тут твой AJAX
    });
});
```

Что ещё будет непонятно спрашивай.

Comment: после добавления ajax в консоли ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (cart:164)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)                          
    `$.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'html',
                url: '<?php echo url('/cart/removeItem');?>/'+rowId,
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $('#cart').html(response);
            } }); `

Comment: @Александр это известный косяк слим-версии 3.2.1, подключи обычную (не слим) и проблема уйдёт.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать **data** - атрибут:

```
<button class="btn" id="removeItem" data-row-id="{{ $cartItem->rowId }}">
```

С помощью **jquery** можно получить следующим образом:

```
var rowId = $('#removeItem').data('rowId');
```